# WPF dynamically add rows of TextBoxes to Grid layout

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I have a window in WPF which contains a `Grid`. The `Grid` initially has one row and a `TextBox` in that row. When the user clicks a `Button`, I have to add a row to the grid with another `TextBox`. While this seems doable, I need to the grid to be scrollable when the rows exceed the height of the grid. (this sort of resembles how you add attachments to email. You add one, and then say add one more..and the list goes on). Am I going about this the right way or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It seems like a good way to me. You only need to wrap around Grid with ScrollViewer, and there shouldn't be any problems. I suggest that you try it and see how it behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't answer whether you're going about it the right way as you've not supplied any code.

Here's how I'd do it. My view models:

```
public class AttachmentInfo : ViewModel
{
    public string Path { get/set omitted }
}

public class EmailInfo : ViewModel
{
    public ICollection<AttachmentInfo> Attachments { get omitted }

    public ICommand AddAttachmentCommand { get omitted }

    // logic for adding attachment simply adds another item to Attachments collection
}
```

In my view, something like this:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Attachments}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
<Button Command="{Binding AddAttachmentCommand}">Add</Button>
```